# Verify that an uploaded file is a word document in Python

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, boto

In my web app (Flask) I'm letting the user upload a word document.

I check that the extension of the file is either `.doc` or `.docx` .
However, I changed a `.jpg` file's extension to `.docx` and it passed as well (as I expected).

Is there a way to verify that an uploaded file is indeed a word document? I searched and read something about the header of a file but could not find any other information.

I'm using boto to upload the files to aws, in case it matters.
Thanks.

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937350/how-to-check-type-of-files-without-extensions-in-python

Comment: This might help: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, that `python-magic` library in the question linked in the comments looks like a pretty straight-forward solution.

Nevertheless, I'll give a more manual option. According to [this site](http://www.filesignatures.net/), DOC files have a signature of `D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1` (8 bytes), while DOCX files have `50 4B 03 04` (4 bytes). Both have an offset of 0. It's safe to assume that the files are little-endian since they're from Microsoft (though, maybe Office files are Big Endian on Macs? I'm not sure)

You can unpack the binary data using the `struct` module like so:

```
>>> with open("foo.doc", "rb") as h:
...    buf = h.read()
>>> byte = struct.unpack_from("<B", buf, 0)[0]
>>> print("{0:x}".format(byte))
d0
```

So, here we unpacked the first little-endian ("<") byte ("B") from a buffer containing the binary data read from the file, at an offset of 0 and we found "D0", the first byte in a doc file. If we set the offset to 1, we get CF, the second byte.

Let's check if it is, indeed, a DOC file:

```
def is_doc(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as h:
        buf = h.read()
    fingerprint = []
    if len(buf) > 8:
        for i in range(8):
            byte = struct.unpack_from("<B", buf, i)[0]
            fingerprint.append("{0:x}".format(byte))
    if ' '.join(fingerprint).upper() == "D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1":        
        return True
    return False

>>> is_doc("foo.doc")
True
```

Unfortunately I don't have any DOCX files to test on but the process should be the same, except you only get the first 4 bytes and you compare against the other fingerprint.

Comment: Note that you may just be able to read `buf[:8]` directly. I profess ignorance as to whether or not that would behave the same on all systems. The `struct.unpack_from` method is guaranteed to work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Docx files are actually zip files. This zip contains three basic folders: `word`, `docProps` and `_rels`. Thus, use `zipfile` to test if those files exist in this file.

```
import zipfile

def isdir(z, name):
   return any(x.startswith("%s/" % name.rstrip("/")) for x in z.namelist())

def isValidDocx(filename):
  f = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, "r")
  return isdir(f, "word") and isdir(f, "docProps") and isdir(f, "_rels")
```

Code adapted from [Check if a directory exists in a zip file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617450/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-zip-file-with-python)

However, any ZIP that contains those folders will bypass the verification.
I also don't know if it works for DOC or for encrypted DOCS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python-docx library

The below code will raise value error is the file is not a docx file.

```
from docx import Document
try:
    Document("abc.docx")
except ValueError:
    print "Not a valid document type"
```

Comment: The exception which will actually be raised is `BadZipFile`

Answer (score 1):

`python-magic` does a very good job of detecting `docx` as well as `pptx` formats.

Here are a few examples:

```
In [60]: magic.from_file("oz123.docx")
Out[60]: 'Microsoft Word 2007+'

In [61]: magic.from_file("oz123.docx", mime=True)
Out[61]: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'

In [62]: magic.from_file("presentation.pptx")
Out[62]: 'Microsoft PowerPoint 2007+'

In [63]: magic.from_file("presentation.pptx", mime=True)
Out[63]: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'
```

Since the OP asked about a file upload, a file handle isn't very useful. Luckily,
`magic` support detecting from buffer:

```
In [63]: fdox
Out[63]: <_io.BufferedReader name='/home/oz123/Documents/oz123.docx'>

In [64]: magic.from_buffer(fdox.read(2048))
Out[64]: 'Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Naively, we read an amount which is too small ... Reading more bytes solves the problem:

```
In [65]: fdox.seek(0)
Out[65]: 0

In [66]: magic.from_buffer(fdox.read(4096))
Out[66]: 'Microsoft Word 2007+'

In [67]: fdox.seek(0)
Out[67]: 0

In [68]: magic.from_buffer(fdox.read(4096), mime=True)
Out[68]: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `python-magic` to verify whether the file type is a word document.
However Ｉ met a lot of problems. Such as: the different word version or the different software was resulting in different types. So Ｉ gave up the `python-magic`.

Here is my solution.

```
DOC_MAGIC_BYTES = [
    "D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1",
    "0D 44 4F 43",
    "CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 00",
    "DB A5 2D 00",
    "EC A5 C1 00"
]
DOCX_MAGIC_BYTES = [
    "50 4B 03 04"
]

def validate_is_word(content):
    magic_bytes = content[:8]
    fingerprint = []
    bytes_len = len(magic_bytes)
    if bytes_len >= 4:
        for i in xrange(bytes_len):
            byte = struct.unpack_from("<B", magic_bytes, i)[0]
            fingerprint.append("{:02x}".format(byte))
    if not fingerprint:
        return False
    if is_docx_file(fingerprint):
        return True
    if is_doc_file(fingerprint):
        return True
    return False


def is_doc_file(magic_bytes):
    four_bytes = " ".join(magic_bytes[:4]).upper()
    all_bytes = " ".join(magic_bytes).upper()
    return four_bytes in DOC_MAGIC_BYTES or all_bytes in DOC_MAGIC_BYTES


def is_docx_file(magic_bytes):
    type_ = " ".join(magic_bytes[:4]).upper()
    return type_ in DOCX_MAGIC_BYTES
```

You can try this.

Comment: Same magic bytes are returned if the file type is excel and powerpoint. How to differentiate further.

Comment: Take a look in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544353/492620

Answer (score 0):

I use filetype python lib to check and compare mime type with its document extension so my users can't fool me just by changing their file extension.

`pip install filetype`

Then

```
import filetype

kind = filetype.guess('path/to/file')
mime = kind.mime
ext = kind.extension
```

You can check their doc [here](https://h2non.github.io/filetype.py/v0.1.3/)

Comment: I think `filetype` library is meant to check only images and pdf files ( as of 8/19) and other related types but not any type of word documents. I actually tried it and it returns `none` even for most valid word document. I think they'll be adding soon.

Comment: This still library does not support docx format.